# 2d Car steering algorithm with left and right?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-engine, game-physics

I'm pretty new to programming and have only "programmed" apps in the game creator Gamesalad before. I have a game on the Appstore that i want to update because it is really buggy and slow. I would be glad if someone could help me putting this piece of code together. The car is basically constantly moving forward and their is no break button. The problem i seem to not be able to figure out it that it needs to work whatever direction the car is moving.

```
// User pressed start game button
- (IBAction)Begin:(id)sender {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(movement1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        Hide.hidden = YES;
    }

// BOOL for left or right
- (IBAction)Leftdown1:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%hhd",left1);
    left1 = YES;
}

- (IBAction)Left1up:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"%hhd",left1);
    left1 = NO;
}

- (IBAction)Right1down:(id)sender {
    right1 = YES;
}

- (IBAction)Right1up:(id)sender {
    right1 = NO;
}

    // movement1 getting called every 0.01 seconds
    -(void)movement1{
    if (left1) {
        //here i don't know what to do. I suppose i need to use cosines. The code below is just me testing.
        point1 = CGPointMake(point1.x-1, point1.y-1);
    } else {
        point1 = CGPointMake(point1.x+1, point1.y+1);
    }

      if (right1) {
        point1 = CGPointMake(point1.x-1, point1.y-1);
    } else {
        point1 = CGPointMake(point1.x+1, point1.y+1);
    }

    car.center = point1;
}
```

Comment: Pay more attention in trig class.

Comment: Well I'm just 16 and I'm going through the trig class after the holiday.

Comment: Well, crack some books.  Basic trig is not that hard.  You can learn what you need to know in a few hours.  (This is stuff you need to know for the sort of game you have -- you can't depend others to do your work for you.  But if you're stuck on a point, ask at http://math.stackexchange.com/.)

Comment: If you are still in school and are just starting with trigonometry and if you are interested in computer graphics, take your time and learn trigonometry (and linear algebra once you get to that) really well.

Comment: Fixed it!, took me a while to figure out thought.